# When is the maximal element guaranteed by Zorn's Lemma unique?

Tags: logic, set-theory, order-theory

Zorn's Lemma states that any poset with the property that every chain has an upper has at least one maximal element. Are there necessary or sufficient conditions on the poset for the maximal element to be provably unique?

I'm thinking in the context of a poset within a larger structure. For example, in the case of ideals ordered by set containment, are there any conditions on the ideal $I_0$ such that  $I_0 \subset I_1, I_2 \implies I_1 = I_2$, where $I_1$ and $I_2$ are maximal ideals? Are there concrete examples of posets where this is known to be true?

Comment: when the order is linear?

Comment: If the poset has a greatest element, then the hypothesis of Zorn's lemma is satisfied, so I don't think you'll find any useful conditions.

Comment: If the maximal element $x$ is unique, then for any other 'potential maximal candidate' $y$ you'd have $x\geq y$. Thus it'd have to be a linear (total) order. The idea behind maximal elements is that different chains may branch off to different maximal elements of each chains, but when it is unique there are no other chains.

Comment: @Panda Are you suggesting that only a linear order can have a greatest element? That's certainly not true

Comment: @samerivertwice: Do not add meta comments to posts, especially when the post is not your own, and especially when you're not the original poster. If you want to see this reopened, use [meta] for the chat.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's hard to know what exactly counts as an answer to this question - of course there's there trivial sufficient suggested in the comments, namely "the poset has a greatest element". But you want a *useful* condition, along the same lines as the usual statement of Zorn's Lemma, that you could apply to a poset whose structure you understand "locally" but not "globally".

Here's a suggestion of such a condition:

> Suppose $(P,\leq)$ is a poset. $P$ has a greatest element if and only if:
>
> 1. Every chain in $P$ has an upper bound.
> 2. $P$ is upward-directed: for all $x$ and $y$ in $P$, there exists $z$ in $P$ such that $x\leq z$ and $y\leq z$.

The proof is easy. If $P$ has a greatest element $m$, then $m$ is an upper bound for every chain and every pair of elements. Conversely, if the two conditions above are satisfied, then by (1) and Zorn's Lemma, $P$ has at least one maximal element. Now suppose $x\in P$ is any element. By (2), there exists $n\in P$ such that $m\leq n$ and $x\leq n$. But since $m$ is maximal, $m = n$, so $x\leq m$. Thus $m$ is the greatest element of $P$.

So for example: Looking at the poset of proper ideals in a nonzero commutative ring $R$, you can check (1) and apply Zorn's Lemma to get a maximal ideal in $R$. If additionally you can prove (2), then you would get that $R$ has a unique maximal ideal ($R$ is a *local* ring).

In this case, (2) amounts to showing that if $I$ and $J$ are proper ideals, then the ideal $(I+J)$ generated by $I$ and $J$ is proper. Equivalently, if $1_R = i+j$ for any two elements $i,j\in R$ then either $i$ or $j$ is a unit - this is a well-known characterization of local rings.

Comment: I would really appreciate if you would give some thought to this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3830353/ in relation to your answer here. Because in that question $\langle2,3\rangle$ can be made a lower bound and uniqueness of it as a minimum decides the Collatz conjecture. There are some defects in that question in the sense that I can rewrite some parts of it with a topology that more clearly shows how $\langle2,3\rangle$ is a bound - I'd be happy to chat about it if you were willing.

Comment: @samerivertwice Sorry, I can't make heads or tails of what you've written there, and I don't have time right now to engage in an extended discussion about it. I am highly skeptical that Zorn's lemma has anything to do with the Collatz conjecture.

Comment: ok thanks for the reply. p.s. I suspect every element being comparable also gives an answer to *this* question.

Comment: @samerivertwice By "every element being comparable", do you mean "every pair of elements is comparable", i.e. the order is linear? A linear order is a special case of an upward-directed order (you can take $z$ to be whichever of $x$ or $y$ is greater).

Comment: I'm imagining a Hasse diagram with a connected directed graph. I see now this is different to comparable.  It sounds like this answer generalises my vague idea and adds some precision.